# Limpiar texto al deseleccionar checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un `<input type="text">` que se despliega al seleccionar el `checkbox` y al desmarcarlo se oculta el `input text`.
Sin embargo quiero que si lo seleccione el `checkbox` y escribí sobre el `textbox` al deseleccionar el `checkbox` este automáticamente se limpie.

El script me sirve para ocultar y mostrar el textbox.

```js
function show_hide() {
  if (document.getElementById('check_sh').checked) {
    document.getElementById('select_sh').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('select_sh').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check_sh" onclick="show_hide() " checked>

<input type="text" name="sele" id="select_sh">
```

Comment: Puedes explicar con un poco más de detalle el problema? Puedes adjuntar el html mínimo para tu ejemplo? Con textbox te refieres a textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que asignar una cadena vacía al valor del `input` cuando el `checkbox` no esté selecionado, de esta manera

```
document.getElementById('select_sh').value = '';
```

Un ejemplo funcional:

```js
function show_hide() {
  if (document.getElementById('check_sh').checked) {
    document.getElementById('select_sh').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('select_sh').value = '';
    document.getElementById('select_sh').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check_sh" onclick="show_hide() " checked>

<input type="text" name="sele" id="select_sh">
```

Answer (score 1):

para poner "limpiar" el input tan solo debes asignar un valor null algo asi:

```js
function show_hide() {
      if (document.getElementById('check_sh').checked) {
        document.getElementById('select_sh').style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('select_sh').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('select_sh').value=null;
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check_sh" onclick="show_hide() " checked>
    
<input type="text" name="sele" id="select_sh">
```

Si te fijas tan solo agregue la linea:

```
document.getElementById('select_sh').value=null;
```

misma que es encargada de establecer como null al input , espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Perfecto, me funciono de maravilla, tienes idea como puedo hacer lo mismo pero en un select?
Es decir que al deseleccionar el checkbox el select tenga un value="--"